# How to compare whether two images are almost identical?

Tags: image, image-processing

I am looking for an algorithmic way of comparing a given pair of images. The comparison has to be tolerant to minor variations

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to open the image using imageio.read(*filename*) and find the absolute difference between the sum of the squares in the arrays to find "*closeness*" between images. You could then implement a tolerance threshold to determine whether they are close enough to be considered almost identical.

For an image:
[image]

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

image = imageio.imread('test1.jpg')

image_sum = np.sum(image**2)

pic1 = imageio.imread('test2.jpg')
pic2 = imageio.imread('random.jpeg')

pic1_sum = np.sum(pic1**2)
pic2_sum = np.sum(pic2**2)

distance_from_pic1 = abs(image_sum - pic1_sum)
distance_from_pic2 = abs(image_sum - pic2_sum)

print(distance_from_pic1)
print(distance_from_pic2)

*Outputs:*
52588
382196481
```

Where pic1 is:
[image: pic1]

and pic 2 is:

[image: pic2]

Hope this helped!